# Drupal 7 Compatibility with PHP 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, php-7

Is the latest version of Drupal 7 (7.54 now in 2017) compatible with PHP 7?

It looks like version 8 is, but the information seems not very clear for version 7.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal core is (should) be compatible, but problem are 3rd party modules. Some of them are, but some are not.

Comment: Yes a lot of module doesn't have release for php7 and use several old deprecated functions

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
So basically, there is no way to know if modules are compatible with PHP 7?

Comment: @filnug hum i think the best method is to install a new drupal with latest version under php 7 , and install & test one by one module and see which works or not ..

Comment: You can't know until you try for your self. Sad but true.

Comment: what are some known modules that has issues so far ?

Answer (score 2):

**Core - updated 14 Mar 2019:**

D6 LTS 6.45 and later supports PHP 7.2.
(D6 LTS will last until at least Feb 2020).

D7 core is now compatible with PHP 7.2 (since Drupal 7.61). PHP 7.3 support is coming.
(D7 end of life is Nov 2021, with long term support to follow).

D8 core: 8.5 supports PHP 7.2, and PHP 7.3 since Drupal 8.6.4.

- [Drupal 6 Long term support PHP 7 blog post](https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/announcing-drupal-645-and-selected-contrib-php-72)
- [Drupal 7 PHP requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/drupal-7-php-requirements#php_required) - note the caveats, including xjm's edit in January
- [Drupal 8 PHP requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/drupal-8-php-requirements) - a table of supported + recommended versions.
- [drupal.org issue - testbot patch to test Drupal 7 PHP7 compatibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2656548)
- [drupal.org "meta" issue - PHP7 support in D7 and 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2454439)

**Modules:**

On a project page, if you click the 'Automated Testing' link at the top, it'll show which tests pass (for PHP version and MySQL version).

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to find out if your code base is PHP 7 compatible, including contrib and custom modules and libraries, is to use a static analysis tool. Such a tool will search through your code and print out a report of any incompatibilities and deprecated code.

I have used [PHP 7 Migration Assistant Report (MAR)](https://github.com/Alexia/php7mar), which works pretty well, though it hasn't been updated recently.

You could also take a look at [Phan](https://github.com/phan/phan) or [PHP Static Analysis Tool](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan).

Many contributed modules do not have tests set up for PHP 7 yet, nor do they list their compatibility, leaving the users to wonder. Analyzing the code with a tool such as these provides you with an estimate of how up-to-date the modules are.